# Fetching place details (specifically reviews) with GooglePlaces in Python 3

Tags: python, google-places-api

I am completely new to this module and Python in general, yet wanted to start some sort of a fun project in my spare time.
I have a specific question concerning the GooglePlaces module for Python - how do I retrieve the reviews of a place by only knowing its Place ID.

So far I have done...

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

google_places = GooglePlaces('API KEY')

query_result = google_places.get_place(place_id="ChIJB8wSOI11nkcRI3C2IODoBU0")

print(query_result) #<Place name="Starbucks", lat=48.14308250000001, lng=11.5782337>

print(query_result.get_details()) # Prints None

print(query_result.rating) # Prints the rating of 4.3
```

I am completely lost here, because I cannot get access to the object's details. Maybe I am missing something, yet would be very thankful for any guidance through my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are completly lost just read the docs :)

Example from https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places:

```
for place in query_result.places:
    # Returned places from a query are place summaries.

    # The following method has to make a further API call.
    place.get_details()
    # Referencing any of the attributes below, prior to making a call to
    # get_details() will raise a googleplaces.GooglePlacesAttributeError.
    print place.details # A dict matching the JSON response from Google.
```

See the Problem with your code now?

```
print(query_result.get_details()) # Prints None
```

should be

```
query_result.get_details() # Fetch details
print(query_result.details) # Prints details dict
```

Regarding the results, the [Google Docs](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details) states:

> reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews. If a language parameter
>   was specified in the Place Details request, the Places Service will
>   bias the results to prefer reviews written in that language. Each
>   review consists of several components:

Comment: Thank you very much, so dumb of me to miss that!
I have one more question if you don't mind: is there a way to get the "newest" reviews instead of "most relevant" ones?

Comment: Happens to all of us :). As far as I know that is not possible (but I may be wrong). The Google Docs state only: "reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews. If a language parameter was specified in the Place Details request, the Places Service will bias the results to prefer reviews written in that language. Each review consists of several components: "